# Best way to handle height with angular-deckGrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grid

So I'm using the angular-deckgrid plugin which creates a responsive pinterest like grid.

Really cool plugin between.

I'm only facing one little problem which only appears when I have a lot of items in my grid.
At some point there start to be a hole in columns, simply because all columns have not the same height. And this is due to the fact that images have not the same height neither.

The thing is that angular-deckgrid places the items in the grid in a strict logical order and does  considerate the height of the images.

Here the part of the code where the colums are created:

```
    Deckgrid.prototype.$$createColumns = function $$createColumns () {
        var self = this;

        if (!this.$$scope.layout) {
            return $log.error('angular-deckgrid: No CSS configuration found (see ' +
                               'https://github.com/akoenig/angular-deckgrid#the-grid-configuration)');
        }

        this.$$scope.columns = [];

        angular.forEach(this.$$scope.model, function onIteration (card, index) {
            var column = (index % self.$$scope.layout.columns) | 0;

            if (!self.$$scope.columns[column]) {
                self.$$scope.columns[column] = [];
            }

            card.$index = index;
            self.$$scope.columns[column].push(card);
        });
    };
```

My question is now basically , what should I do? I Have 3 options.

1. Looking for an other plugin
2. Looking for a fork which handles this problem
3. Rewrite this method myself

I would like not to do the 3rd one if a solution already exists but if I have to I will.

But in this case how to identify the height of the images without knowing it ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Need load the card into column while set to visibility hidden, wait until everything loaded and get the rendered size, finally show the card. Maybe switch to angular-masonry is a easier way out.